# How to connect to Infura Testnet by using WebsocketProvider?

Tags: web3js, websocket

I want to connect to rinkeby.infura testnet by using WebsocketProvider but the page remains blocked to load.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

console.log(Web3.givenProvider);

var web3 = new Web3( new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws'));

var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x8789497B837437632143efFb87d74F40D4EDDcFe'
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(log);
});


// unsubscribes the subscription
subscription.unsubscribe((error, success) => {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
});
```

The current version of web3 is: 1.0.0-beta.34

Answer (score 1):

Check if the page is accessible first. Sometimes the page itself may be down, happened for me with Ropsten

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76311/discussion-on-answer-by-madan-how-to-connect-to-infura-testnet-by-using-websocke).